# Stopped upgrade to 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS midway, now cannot do sudo apt update and upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

So, I'd been waiting for the 22.04 LTS version to release on sudo dist upgrade and immediately started to follow the steps [here][1] to upgrade it via the official "safe" method. I followed the steps till the part where I had to enter yes/no for the prompt:

```
X number of packages are going to be removed
Removing the packages can take several hours
```

I decided against upgrading later and didnt notice that the prompt had an option for answering No for the upgrade and spammed Ctrl+C and Ctrl+D since they usually stop terminal processes midway. Neither worked, so I closed the terminal window that was stuck partially in the upgrade and killed that process.
(definitely at fault for this part right here^)

The partial upgrade rewrote my sources.list file and replaced the "focal" list sources with "jammy" sources. Here is one instance of it found in the`/etc/apt/` directory

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
```

The "focal" sources were commented out and "jammy" sources were added. Neither sudo apt update nor sudo apt-get update worked (the hits for the third-party softwares became invalid), so I modified the `sources.list` file to the default version that Ubuntu 20.04 ships with. Its current contents are:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update` now work, but they only hit those default sources and none of the third party software sources were there.
I'd prepared a backup file (sources.listdefault.bak) that had the contents of `sources.list` before the upgrade, its contents:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
cassandra.list   #line 15
cassandra.list.distUpgrade
cassandra.list.save
home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list
home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list.distUpgrade
home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list.save
...etc
```

Copied these lines into the sources.list file but now a new error creeps up when I run sudo apt update:

```
E: Malformed line 15 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

FYI: line 15 is where my third party software sources start from, they're preceded by the original working "focal" sources.
The result of `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` is:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 133, in <module>
    m = MetaReleaseCore(useDevelopmentRelease=options.devel_release,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 100, in __init__
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 170, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 232, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Malformed line 15 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type), E:The list of sources could not be read.
```

What I think has happened is that Ubuntu thinks that it is actually 22.04 but because of me stopping the upgrade partially, some of the stuff is still 20.04 (`lsb_release -a` says so too). How do I go about fixing this issue (apt unable to update my third party sources)? Am I stuck with an invalid version of Ubuntu thats neither 20.04 nor 22.04 and I have to nuke the OS itself? Im ready to back up my system and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, but I'd rather see my options and see whether I can resume my update from where it left off or just completely downgrade to the plain old 20.04 it was.

TL,DR: Stopped upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 midway and might be stuck with a frankensystem

I've also read comment [2] related to another partial upgrade issue, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.
Will provide any other details required. Thanks for reading through this long post and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: There was a clear warning that the process can only be stopped during the download process, before packages start to be installed. The first packages upgraded are python/package related, meaning if it's stopped; recovery of your backups are the safest way out, as you cannot reverse any other way, and may or may not be able to continue (*depending where you stopped it; why it provided the warning at the start!*).   **If** you stopped it before packages were actually installed; you can just revert your source changes (it'll have done that for you if you didn't stop it but used cancel operations)

Comment: Please define *midway* - was it still downloading?  or had it started installing the first package?